# Как задать ширину для фона текста?

Tags: html, css

пытаюсь с помощью `width` указать ширину для фона текста, но реакции никакой
Она должна быть распростерта по всей ширине блока, но ограничивается лишь, когда заканчивается последняя буква текста.

```css
.row {
  max-width: 700px
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background: #red;
  border: 2px solid #red;
  padding: 5px;
}

.gip {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="gip">
  <a href="#"><b>Текст</a></b>
</div>
```

Comment: всё, ребят, не нужно. нашел команду. 
display: block.